# Absolute Coordinates in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

What is the simplest way to determine absolute object coordinates in AS3?

Answer (score 4):

`(foo as DisplayObject).localToGlobal(new Point(x,y));`

Answer (score 0):

var absolutePoint:Point = DisplayObject(foo).localToGlobal(new Point(foo.x, foo.y));